# Find a rectification transformation in $a = (1,-1)$ for system of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, linear-transformations

For the following system
\begin{align*}
     \dot{x_1} &= x_1+x_2^2\\
     \dot{x_2} &= -1
 \end{align*}
I need to find a rectification transformation $x = (x_1, x_2) \mapsto y = y(x) = (y_1(x), y_2(x))$, in the point $a = (1,-1)$ such that
\begin{align*}
     \dot{y_1} &= 1\\
     \dot{y_2} &= 0
 \end{align*}

I tried to transform the system with several transformation. For example, $y_1=x_1-1$ and $y_2 = x_2+1$. I tried changing to polar coordinates but again the same problem. I do not get $\dot{y}_1$ and $\dot{y}_2$. My question is, there exists a method to find that rectification transformation or I have to keep searching that function?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In one very obvious way you need to take $y_1=-x_2$ and as $y_2$ the integration constant of the first equation, or their quotient $\frac{dx_1}{dx_2}=-x_1-x_2^2$.

Comment: What do you mean for the integration constant?

Comment: You get $x_1=\phi(x_2,C)$. Set $y_2=C$, then $\dot y_2=0$ along a solution curve.

Comment: You are right! Thanks, I did that.